# Select table row using HQL with param

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to use this HQL query in order to select table row value:

```
String hql = "select e.token, e.name from Terminals e where e.token = ?";
Terminals terminal = entityManager
    .createQuery(hql, Terminals.class)
    .setParameter(0, terminalToken)
    .getSingleResult();
```

But I get this result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [org.api.entity.Terminals]
```

What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Your query return two Objects `token` and `name` and not a `Terminals` Object.

Instead you can use :

```
Object[] obj = entityManager
    .createQuery(hql)
    .setParameter(0, terminalToken)
    .getSingleResult();

if(obj != null){
    Terminals terminal = new Terminals((String) obj[0], (String) obj[1]);
}
```

---

Or you can create a constructor in Terminals class which hold two fields :

```
public Terminals(String token, String name){
   this.token = token;
   this.name = name;
}
```

then change your code to be :

```
String hql = "select new com.package.Terminals(e.token, e.name) from Terminals e where e.token = ?";
Terminals terminal = entityManager
    .createQuery(hql, Terminals.class)
    .setParameter(0, terminalToken)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: By the way is there a better more simple way?

Comment: @PeterPenzov mmm I'm not sure, all I know is this two ways, unless you want to return the full Object you don't need all that just change your query to be `"select e from Terminals e where e.token = ?";` this will return the full Terminals Object

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just change your query to be `"select e from Terminals e where e.token = ?";`

Comment: I updated the code but the selected object values are null. Any idea why?

Comment: @PeterPenzov are you sure you have a value with the token you enter in your database?

Comment: Yes, anyway I will try to hard code the value just to test.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should not directly call `createQuery` to assign to a custom object. And there is a possiblity of returning a list.

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, "something");<br>
List<Object[]> terminals = query.getResultList();
```

and retrieve the objects with an index as the ff as an example:

```
        StudentDto dto = new StudentDto();
        for(Object[] a: std) {
            dto = new StudentDto();
            dto.setId((long) a[0]); //id
            dto.setName(a[1].toString()); //first name
            dto.setPassportNumber(a[2].toString()); //last name
        }
```